# Where do I set that agent certificate for Puppet on Amazon Linux?

Tags: dns, puppet

I am using:

- Puppet server version: 1.2.0
- Amazon Linux 2

I have master and agent set in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf and currently I get back only the certificate for the master on the master. The agent's DNS name under [agent] and [main] is

certname = doug2c.mylabserver.com

but

`puppet cert list -all`   returns:

```
+ "doug1c.mylabserver.com" (SHA256) C2:AE:78:00:8D:EE:40:09:06:26:10:AD:82:47:58:26:C7:86:F5:A1:8A:D8:B1:BE:81:C2:AF:D1:70:F9:04:EF (alt names: "DNS:doug1c.mylabserver.com", "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.mylabserver.com")
```

I tried useing find to locate where it was set to puppet with

```
find / -name doug1c
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

On the agent I needed to set the server ip set to puppet in 
/etc/hosts

I had accidentally put it on the agents ip address and then been incorrectly assuming i'd done something wrong on the master rather than the agent.

(server ip)  (domian name)   puppet